# METEOR/BLAZE/IRON _Apply css and execute JS after layout loaded failed without error

Tags: html, css, meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

I have problem with the loading css and executing js when i use Meteor/Blaze/iron Router when layouts are used, i should reload the page if i want to apply style and execute js.

The layout html file

```
<template name="mainSkell">
  {{>topnav}}
  <!-- page content -->
  <div class="right_col" role="main">
    {{>action_menu}}
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
        {{>yield}}
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        {{>activity}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /page content -->
</template>
```

Router js file

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'mainSkell'
});

Router.route('/', {}, function () {
  this.render('mainSkell');
});


Router.route('/Pserver', {name: 'createPserver'}, function () {
  this.render('createPserver');
});

Router.route('/Racks', {name: 'createRacks'}, function () {
  this.render('createRacks');
});
```

The routing work with one issue, css and custom js don't work when i click link.

Screenshot whith direct link access
[Pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLI92.png)

Screenshot when link is actived
[Not working css & js Pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUoiD.png)

Comment: Did you try anything? Show some code please.

Comment: Hello,

My problem is not generated by iron Router, this problem is regarding Blaze rended template and js already ready $(document).ready(.

on.('load' not work because the Blaze Template is loaded and the element are not newly created.

I'm still working on this problem ... if any one have solution please advise me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's **solved** now, the solution is very simple.
:)
Just add scripts under the template itself

```
<template name="mytemp">
  <!-- HTML CODE -->
  <script src="/build/js/custom.js"></script>
  <script src="/build/js/guiaction.js"></script>
</template>
```